# How to push web-pack runtime into specific entry chunk when there are multiple entry chunks?

Tags: caching, webpack, runtime, chunks, webpack-2

Ideally vendor chunk hash should not change but when ever app code changes vendor chunk hash is also getting changed. Want to extract webpack-runtime from vendor chunk and put it in another entry chunk 'main'

```js
entry: {
    // entry point for vendor chunk and main chunk
    vendor: ['react', 'react-redux', 'react-dom',
      'universal-router', 'react-visibility-sensor', 'memoizee'],
    main: './client.js'
  },

  output: {
    filename: DEBUG ? '[name].js?[chunkhash]' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: DEBUG ? '[name].[id].js?[chunkhash]' : '[name].[id].[chunkhash].js',
  },

  target: 'web'



// Emit a file with assets paths
    // https://github.com/sporto/assets-webpack-plugin#options
    new AssetsPlugin({
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
      filename: 'assets.js',
      processOutput: x => `module.exports = ${JSON.stringify(x)};`,
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'common',
      // create a additional chunk for the common modules
      // which is loaded in parallel to the requested chunks.
      // name the chunks whose common chunk need to be created
      chunks: ['main', 'Home'],
      async: false
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      // min number of chunks that are requesting the vendor module
      minChunks: 2
    }),
```

Comment: i can add one more extra chunk for webpack-runtime by editing as `new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'runtime'] }) ` but i want to add to existing chunks not a new one